# We are unable to run "Project Status" or "Requirement Coverage" Reports (with module failing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, tarantula

Recently, we found that when running certain reports (Either Project Status or Requirement Coverage) the report fails with a popup showing:

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Examining the **httpd access logs** I see the following:

"GET /report/requirement_coverage/?sort_by=id&test_object_ids=12 HTTP/1.1" 403 38 "http://tarantula.xxxxx.xxxx/"

**in the production.log file, we also see this:**

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass 
/opt/tarantula/rails/lib/priority_extensions.rb:9:in`priority_name' 
/opt/tarantula/rails/app/models/report/requirement_coverage.rb:115:in `case_info' 
/opt/tarantula/rails/app/models/report/requirement_coverage.rb:77:in`block (2 levels) in do_query' 
/opt/tarantula/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:91:in `each' 
/opt/tarantula/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:91:in`method_missing' 
/opt/tarantula/rails/app/models/report/requirement_coverage.rb:77:in `block in do_query' 
/opt/tarantula/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:6:in`each' 
/opt/tarantula/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:6:in `each' 
/opt/tarantula/rails/app/models/report/requirement_coverage.rb:66:in`do_query'

lots more under this followd by:

/opt/tarantula/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `' 
Completed 403 Forbidden in 113381.4ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 7849.2ms)

NOTE: this is not my code, but code from a module of Testia Tarantula

```
=begin rdoc

Include this in a model which is to be prioritized.

 =end
 module PriorityExtensions

   def priority_name
     Project::Priorities.detect{|p| p[:value] == self.priority}[:name]
   end

   def priority=(p)
     if p.is_a? String
       p_val = Project::Priorities.detect{|pp| pp[:name] == p.downcase}
       if p_val
         self[:priority] = p_val[:value]
       else
         raise "Invalid priority '#{p}' for #{self.class} (id #{self.id})"
       end
     else
       self[:priority] = p
     end
   end

   def self.included(model)
     model.validates_inclusion_of :priority, :in =>           Project::Priorities.map{|p| p[:value]}
   end

 end
```

Comment: OK, so where's your code?

Comment: Found the issue, a column "priority" in the table "cases", had somehow been changed to NULL.  Changed the value to '0' (normal) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, a column "priority" in the table "cases", had somehow been changed to an invalid NULL. Changing the value to '0' (normal) fixed the issue.